# Can kernel guarantee that POSIX close frees the descriptor?

Tags: linux-kernel, file-descriptors, system-calls

Linux developers argue that it's pointless to retry `close` operation in case of an [error](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/close.2.html#NOTES), since the kernel "always releases the file descriptor **early**" (emphasis mine).

While in general fildes state in face of EINTR is undefined, is it **always** well-defined on Linux?

Does kernel have any means (atomic instructions, interrupt masking etc.) to guarantee that **early** closing is not interrupted in any way by a non-faulty hardware?

So far, I can see that the syscall takes a [spinlock](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.20.17/source/fs/file.c#L625) before freeing the `fd` which requires callers to ensure IRQ are [disabled](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.20.17/source/kernel/locking/lockdep.c#L3198). Not sure where that happens yet.

Comment: It's all explained in the NOTES in your link, including comparison to other implementations (ie non-linux: mostly same) and posix's stance (silent). There's a specific note about EINTR, linux behaviour and HP-UX behaviour. What more do you need?

Comment: Sorry, but I think that you're completely confused about the mechanism and purpose of interrupting system calls. A system call will not return `EINTR` when a hardware or software interrupt happened, but after a signal handler set by the process is run: if you don't set any signal hander with `sigaction(2)`, etc., you won't get any `EINTR`. Since you can't do much in a signal handler (no, not even a `printf`, though you'll find that in many crappy answers and tutorials), you may want to get out of a blocking `read(2)` or `close(2)` in order to handle the signal in your main program.